# Installing Windows patch from command line gives BSOD but fine if double clicked?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to programatically install some Windows updates that were manually downloaded.  If I double click the `.exe` and run through the install manually - everything works fine.  If I, however, use powershell and type `& mypatch.exe /quiet` and reboot I always get a BSOD with any patch.

Running the above powershell command produces no output (obviously) and has no exit code.  Is there something I'm doing wrong that is causing the BSOD?

The BSOD I get is: `PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED`

EDIT:

I figured out how to use the installer and not get a BSOD from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The `/quiet` switch always gives me a BSOD but if I use `/passive` everything works fine.  I'm still testing, but so far 5 patches have gone in without fail.  If only I could now get the exit code!

Comment: can you share the dmp files from C:\Windows\Minidump?

Comment: @magicandre1981 the problem is when is BSOD I have to do a restore to an earlier date and there is never a minidump file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to work instead of using `& mypatch.exe /quiet /norestart` or `& mypatch.exe /passive /norestart` I used the following:

`Start-Process <path to patch> -Wait -ArgumentList "/quiet /norestart"`

And that works without giving me a BSOD